# Binary search on DateTime ranges

Tags: c#, binary-search

I have a sorted list of `TimeRange` objects. Each `TimeRange` object has a start and end `DateTime` object.

I have a query where I would like to return the `TimeRange`s that fall between a certain range. I currently have a function that looks like the following

```
protected List<TimeRange> GetBoundedTimeRanges(List<TimeRange> timeRanges, DateTime startTime,
        DateTime endTime)
    {
        if (timeRanges == null || timeRanges.Count == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var ranges = new List<TimeRange>();

        foreach (var range in timeRanges)
        {
            // If the end of the range is before the start time
            if (range.End < startTime)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // If the start of the range is after the end time
            // then break. 
            if (range.Start > endTime)
            {
                break;
            }

            // Otherwise the value falls between the range
            ranges.Add(range);
        }

        return ranges;
    }
```

This is pretty slow and I would like to convert the foreach part into a binary search(or any other suitable algorithm) and then copy from the original list into a new list using the binary search however I am unsure how to go about doing so since we have a Start and End Time in each range. Any help would be appreciated.

The ranges do not overlap. For instance the end time of range 0 is always less than the start time of range 1

Examples of ranges

```
Range found - Start Time 03/02/2015 22:51:50, End Time 10/03/2015 15:44:56
Range found - Start Time 10/03/2015 15:46:26, End Time 11/03/2015 08:38:56
Range found - Start Time 11/03/2015 08:43:12, End Time 13/03/2015 04:15:05
Range found - Start Time 13/03/2015 04:15:08, End Time 17/03/2015 13:38:21
Range found - Start Time 17/03/2015 13:40:00, End Time 17/03/2015 15:15:52
Range found - Start Time 17/03/2015 15:19:05, End Time 17/03/2015 15:20:42
Range found - Start Time 17/03/2015 15:39:48, End Time 24/03/2015 16:37:29
Range found - Start Time 24/03/2015 16:42:25, End Time 25/03/2015 07:46:54
Range found - Start Time 25/03/2015 07:50:23, End Time 25/03/2015 15:36:33
Range found - Start Time 25/03/2015 15:40:15, End Time 25/03/2015 15:48:44
Range found - Start Time 25/03/2015 15:52:40, End Time 25/03/2015 15:57:21
Range found - Start Time 25/03/2015 16:01:22, End Time 31/03/2015 09:18:49
Range found - Start Time 31/03/2015 09:22:12, End Time 01/04/2015 10:00:26
```

Comment: Are your time ranges ordered and if so by what criteria? If they are unordered then I'm not sure you can do better than just looking at each one and seeing if it is ok. If it is ordered then the exact algorithm will depend on how it is ordered (eg by start date, end date or something more complicated like midpoint).

Comment: Do ranges overlap or they are non overlapping?'

Comment: The ranges do not overlap. The end time of range 0 is always less than the start time of range 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your List is sorted by start time. You could run a Binary search with a custom comparer to find out where the range could possibly be located.

```
protected List<TimeRange> GetBoundedTimeRanges(List<TimeRange> timeRanges, DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
{
    var startSearch = timeRanges.BinarySearch(new TimeRange(startTime, startTime), new TimeRangeComparer());
    if (startSearch < 0)
    {
        startSearch = ~startSearch;
    }

    var ranges = new List<TimeRange>();
    for (int i = startSearch; i < timeRanges.Count; i++)
    {
        var range = timeRanges[i];
        if (range.End < startTime)
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (range.Start > endTime)
        {
            break;
        }
        ranges.Add(range);
    }

    return ranges;
}

class TimeRangeComparer : IComparer<TimeRange>
{
    public int Compare(TimeRange x, TimeRange y)
    {
        var startResult = x.End.CompareTo(y.Start);
        if (startResult != 0)
        {
            return startResult;
        }

        return x.End.CompareTo(y.End);
    }
}
```

This should perform significantly better than what a linear algorithm does as we're using BinarySearch.

Note: When creating a dummy `TimeRange` instance for searching, I've used `new TimeRange(startTime, startTime)` that's not a typo. It is intentional. We don't care about end time there. We filter the end time in the for loop(which you already have).

Comment: This is quicker but seems to miss out when some of the time range falls between the start and end time. If the range is between 01/01/2014 and the 10/01/2014 and we care about ranges between 02/01/2014/ to 04/01/2014 then that range should be included since it does contain that range(irregarding the fact it also includes a lot of other time too!)

Comment: @const_ref I'm not sure I understand the problem. There may be bugs (obviously). But I hope you got the idea and it isn't fundamentally flawed. Can you show the test which fails with the test data?

Comment: Hey. Using the examples above and passing in a start date of 2015/03/10 and an end date of 2015/03/15 I would expect to return a list of size 4 however I only get a size of 3 back as if the start date is less than 2015/03/10 it does not get included even if the end date is after 2015/03/10

Comment: @const_ref Glad you fixed it. You can either edit my answer with the fix, or edit your question with the final code. So that community will be benefited.